# Receber notificação do google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

É possível configurar o google drive para meu cliente receber um e-mail quando o drive fica um dia sem compartilhar algum arquivo? E estou a procura de como integrar o drive no meu sistema com PHP, para lá meu cliente ter os relatórios de compartilhamentos, já vi alguma coisa parecida, mas não encontrei um conteúdo sobre o mesmo.

Comment: Alisson, explica melhor seu problema, não da para entender direito, como assim ficar um dia sem compartilhar? E teria como adicionar o que tentou fazer? Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

A API do Google Drive possui suporte para o PHP. Você pode usá-la para fazer uma consulta, através de uma tarefa assíncrona escrita em PHP, para verificar diariamente alterações no diretório e enviar e-mails de acordo com suas regras. Essa API também servirá para fazer a integração com seu sistema.

[Neste artigo](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php#step_4_run_the_sample) do Google, você pode seguir o passo a passo de como usar a API.

Veja o exemplo a seguir, contido no link informado acima:

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10,
  'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
  print "No files found.\n";
} else {
  print "Files:\n";
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
  }
}
```

Eu não entendi se o que você precisa é enviar e-mail apenas na ausência de compartilhamento de arquivos, ou trata-se de ausência na criação ou modificação do arquivo, mas para ambos, você pode fazer passando os parâmetros corretos em $optParams['fields'], são eles **modifiedDate** e **sharedWithMeDate**. Depois você trata o resultado e envia os e-mails que precisar.

[Neste link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list), você pode usar o Try it, no final da página, para verificar os parâmetros extras disponíveis na chamada do método listFiles.